# set parent selector as a variable

Tags: less

```
div .mymixin('red','green')    
.mymixin(@a, @b){
  a {
    color: @a;
    span {
      color: @b;
    }
  }
}
```

This code will produce the following css:

```
div a{color:red;}
div a span{color: green;}
```

I need it to produce this:

```
div a{color:red;}
div:not(.open) a span{color: green;}
```

I was trying to do something like this:

```
div .mymixin('red','green')    
@parent: &;
.mymixin(@a, @b){
  a {
    color: @a;
    @{parent}:not(.open) span {
      color: @b;
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work the right way, producing

```
div a &:not(.open) span{color:green;}
```

Is there a way to assign parent to a variable or do it some other way to achieve what I am after?

Thank you.

P.S. Here is the actual nesting I have:

```
.icfld(@name, @width, @height, @opacity, @open) {
  > a {
    ...
    > .icon {
      ...
    }
    &.disabled > .icon {
      ...
    }
    //&:not(.open) :not(.disabled):hover... will NOT work, because & at this point refers to 
    //"parent" > a and makes it "parent" > a:not(.open), while I need "parent":not(.open)
    //the following line, however, works  
    &:not(.disabled):hover {
      & when (@open=false) {
        ...
        > .icon {
          ...
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: The first structure has `div:not(.open) a ...` but the Less nesting looks different. Why not put that outside the `a{}` and define it like `&:not(.open) a span{}`?

Comment: There is a lot going on there in other than what's above, so I can't just separate out the span unless that's the only option. I was hoping to get some sort of parent selector if that's possible at all. But you gave me an idea for a work around. Thank you.

Comment: `&` is the parent selector but with the above nesting the parent would be `div a` (`div` because it calls the mixin and `a` because of nesting). So `&:not(.open)` would produce `div a:not(.open)`.

Comment: It seems like you misinterpret the meaning of `&`, use [something like this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/6dc1b199bd351b216f33#file-26409501-1-less). (To answer the question itself: no, you can't currently use `&` in a selector interpolation but for your use case (as Harry already mentioned) it won't work anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with the following work around:

```
.mymixin2(@a, @b, @open){
  a {
    color: @a;
    & when(@open = false){
      span {
        color: @b;
      }
    }
  }
}
.mymixin1(@a,@b){
  &.open {.mymixin2(@a,@b,true);}
  &:not(.open) {.mymixin2(@a,@b,false);}
}

div .mymixin1('red', 'green');
```

This seems to do the trick.

Comment: It does not look like Less code (it does not even compile, also with all typos fixed it still looks like a perfect example of overengineering).

Comment: why doesn't it look like less and what is overengineered there?

Comment: This is not Less code because you won't be able to compile it. And it's overengineered because it has too much unnecessary code. Yet again see the gist I linked to in my comment above (it's valid Less and it produces the CSS you marked as what you need in the Q).

Comment: I have added the actual nesting that I have to my original post. And your example doesn't work in that case. And it does compile. I might have mistyped something in the answer. I think I fixed all now

Comment: Well, I guess your main mistake with all this is that you're trying to nest everything inside single `a` and this is actual problem. Just split `> a` and `&:not(.open) > a` and you're there (that's what my example is about).